# mergeSubstreamsWithParallelism vs mergeSubstreams

Tags: akka-stream

What is the difference between mergeSubstreams and mergeSubstreamsWithParallelism
I first thought that just a performance difference but when executing this code

```
.groupBy(magicNumber, tuple => tuple._2)
.fold(("", Seq.empty[String]))
{
  case ((_, acc), tuple) => (tuple._2, acc :+ tuple._1)
}
.mergeSubstreams
```

I have a finit stream that give me result.
But with

```
.groupBy(numberIsp, tuple => tuple._2)
.fold(("", Seq.empty[String]))
{
  case ((_, acc), tuple) => (tuple._2, acc :+ tuple._1)
}
.map{x=>println(x);x}
.mergeSubstreamsWithParallelism(10)
```

I have an infinite stream that print nothing.

In my case It's don't make any differences but I would like to now why there is this behavior.

Comment: I think I answered your question completely... please check and see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

Here is exactly what is going wrong.

```
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(system))
  implicit val ctx = implicitly[ExecutionContext](system.dispatcher)

  val Integers = Source(1 to 100).map {
    case n: Int => println(s"n is $n"); n
  }

  // same beginning, same sink, just different merges

  val sameBeginning = Integers.groupBy(5, _ % 3).take(6).fold(0) {
    case (a, b) => a + b
  }.map {
    case n: Int => println(s"Now n is $n !"); n
  }

  def sameSink(id: Int) = Sink.foreach[Int] {
    case n: Int => println(s"Sink $id says - You are done now final val is $n")
  }

  val mergeWithPlenty = sameBeginning.mergeSubstreams.to(sameSink(1)).run()

  val mergeWithNotEnough = sameBeginning.mergeSubstreamsWithParallelism(2).to(sameSink(2)).run()
```

Now, if you run that, you will see *immediately almost*...

```
Sink 1 says - You are done now final val is 51
Sink 1 says - You are done now final val is 57
Sink 1 says - You are done now final val is 63
```

And much, much later...

```
Sink 2 says - You are done now final val is 51
Sink 2 says - You are done now final val is 57
```

Sink 2 doesn't even finish!

I can make it worse... all you have to do is to increase the amount of pressure on Sink 2 in terms of not elements but **dimensions**, or number of substreams.

Sink 1 gets "as many as it can get." Sink 2, by your command, is told to use only a finite number.

If the finite number sufficies, it is not an issue. For instance, take the same example above, but change now Sink 2 to have parallelism 20 or `20 pipes`.

Look what happens!

```
Sink 2 says - You are done now final val is 51
Sink 1 says - You are done now final val is 51
Sink 2 says - You are done now final val is 57
Sink 1 says - You are done now final val is 57
Sink 2 says - You are done now final val is 63
Sink 1 says - You are done now final val is 63
```

Now, Sink 2 is winning, which I cannot explain. I assume that is a race condition, but the point is that when there are excess pipes, it behaves exactly as you would expect.

## Older material..

```
def mergeSubstreams: F[Out] = mergeSubstreamsWithParallelism(Int.MaxValue)
```

Assuming you have the same version of the software, it appears the difference is in the choice of integer you provide for "parallelism," or the number of tolerable concurrent substreams...

Maybe with low parallelism you ended up in a situation with streams unable to complete.

Here's a trivial way to get to your described behavior.

Let's say I have a subflow that adds the elements of `11` elements together concurrently.

You provide a parallelism degree of `10`.

Then your finite sequence of say, 55, should be split into subsequences of `11`... your finite sequence does just fine when there are plenty of pipes available, because it does 5 steps through the subflow. But when there are not, it cant finish, and it appears to be infinite.

Comment: So what's the use of this sub parallelism stream number param ? what is the use case ?

Comment: It probably corresponds by default VERY tightly to the concept of `Thread`, so that 1 pipe open = dim 1 = 1 thread used.

Comment: This is really not very complicated... akka is just letting you choose whether you want to use all your available rsources when making subgroups, or less than that. **If you ask to make 30 things into 6 groups of 5 and feed them all down 3 pipes at once, you're going to have a problem in real life too**